# How to modify _ssl in python

Tags: python, ssl

I want to modify the _ssl module in python. However, I can't find its location. I found ssl.py, but it gives me no clue as to the location of the _ssl module.

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: I want to modify the ssl module so that you can pass in the cert and key class instead of just paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fire up the interpreter and:

```
>>> import _ssl
>>> _ssl
#<module '_ssl' from 'the/location/you/wanted.so'>
```

It's a dynamically loaded library though (`.so`, `.dll`, depending on your platform) though, so it's not possible to just modify it.